# Execute code in .net application when new row is inserted in sql server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms, performance

I am developing a stock market finance application, where I have to generate buy and sell signals based on some custom algorithm.  I am getting data for this from an excel file, which is changed on every tick. I have written Excel VBA for saving data in SQL Server db so that I can use it in my .net application. My calculations are dependent on every tick. One way I can get data into my app is by polling. But I do not think it is a good application design since I have to poll db every second. This is not an optimal solution. So I would like to know If I could execute code in .net when new record is inserted in database (like some kind of insert trigger in .net app).

Other question which is not relevant to title, but is relevant to my application. This is first time I am developing a financial application. So would like to know some tips on optimal handling of data which is streaming every second (in some cases micro seconds). I have to get data, monitor and calculate for every tick without much delay. It is very important that I apply calculations for every tick instantly.  so requesting any one to help me with some tips on application design. The only consolation in this application is the data which I am getting in Excel is for only few selected scrips instead of all scrips which will be very huge.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: lookup SqlDependency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or check out a [SQL-CLR trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/938d9dz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that can be written in C# or VB.NET, and lives inside of SQL Server and gets executed on a given occurrence of an operation (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`). **BE CAREFUL**, though: a trigger should be very lean and nimble - do **NOT** do extensive, time-consuming work inside a trigger! That would kill all performance and scalability of your application!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is it VBA code that updates the Excel file from streaming market data, and then saves data to SQL which in turn needs to trigger some C# code?  Why not just have the VBA call invoke a web method when data are saved to the database?

Comment: @Dan.. No VBA does not update Excel... Market data is streamed in excel from which I used VBA to save data in SQL and Yes to consume data I need some kind of trigger as suggested by marc_s to notify .net c# application .

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks for suggestion. I have checked SQL-CLR Trigger but I think it will be too extensive since market data is streamed in sub-seconds. I am thinking getting data directly from Excel into my app through Excel Automation.

Comment: Using Excel for streaming market data is a kludge at best.  Have you considered market data provider that provides a streaming interface you can use to subscribe to and consume directly from your C# app?  That would provide the best scalability and stability.  With your existing design. I think the either the SqlDependency or method call would be best.

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s mentioned in his comment, the best solution for your immediate problem is probably a CLR trigger which will "call" your .NET process with the new tick data.

Overall, the approach you have taken will not be able to sustain high volumes and will suffer from stability issues over time. Unless you really need to use Excel to receive the tick data (this is often the case if your only source is a Bloomberg terminal, in which case you may want to check on your limits with Bloomberg :), I would strongly advise again using it for streaming data.

Also, most application which consume tick data do not need to persist the data at all. It seems like you are using SQL Server as a messaging layer in your system. Consider a proper messaging solution (a direct process communication like memory-mapper files, sockets or third-party libraries; or a brokered solution like an EMS). Gathering data for back-testing can be done by a separate process.

Comment: thanks for answer... Unfortunately I could get data only in Excel. But my consolation is I'll get data for the scrips I need instead of all market data. Right now I have very few (around 10) scrips to stream data. As you have said, I am considering to get data directly from Excel using Excel automation and use two separate threads. One for charting & calculation and another for saving data in sql.  I hope getting data from excel to .net app does not consume much of a time.